# How to return a value in mongodb async find in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a requirement of returning a Boolean value if document exist in mongodb using async driver in Java.

Here is the sample code

```
`private boolean isRecordExist(Document _doc)
 {
   _collection.find(_doc).first(new SingleResultCallback<Document>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(final Document document, final     Throwable t) {
                            if(document != null)
                            {
                                //this should return "true"
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                //this should return "false"
                            }
                         }
                    });
 }`
```

Is there any work around for this ?